# Display together layer in decimal Lat/Lon & layer in DMS

Tags: qgis

I have several vector layers with DMS location expressed as something like 5148074,130358 and several vector layers with decimal location expressed as something like 42.23,15.2.

All of them having CRS WGS84 and same is the project CRS.

When I try do display them, they not overlay (although they should): QGIS treats the numbers as is, which means lat 42 and lat 5148074.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you store your DMS locations in a text file? In QGIS you can create a layer from a delimited text file and tick 'DMS coordinates' while importing. After that your DMS layer will be converted into normal decimal degree coordinates.

Comment: you say that "All of them having CRS WGS84". This MUST be wrong for those layers with 7/6 digits. Assign the correct projected CRS to them, then QGIS is able to reproject them on the fly to WGS84. Even better, reproject all other layers to your projected CRS. Doing spatial stuff in LatLon is not that convenient in QGIS as with projected data. But you seem to be no newbie, so maybe I just got your words wrong ...

Comment: Unless he means 5148074==51°48'07.4"N.  But that does not seem highly likely.

Comment: @JimT the "5148074" is the result of the well known conversion like 42*60+34*60 or something like this.

Comment: @BerndV. You suggest to right click on each layer and set the original CRS, and then why QGIS will change that to WGS84-how to force that? Regarding you comment "Doing spatial stuff in LatLon is not that convenient" - What you mean here? What is the alternative to Latitude & Longitude?

Comment: If it is DMS then it's packed dms, DDMMSSs or DDMMSS and pretty much  most GIS won't be able to do anything with it. Are the given values actual values? And if so, what location does the data represent? That information could help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: ah, I'm awfully sorry. I did't get that thing with the DMS. So, forget everything I wrote so far ;)